# Import csv data into Mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, csv, import

We receive a csv-file for updating our order database.

Now in the file there is a tracking code. In the csv file it displays as `f.i. 26E+12`. This is a scientific number. When I click the cell it shows as 563200000 or something like that.

Now we are running a cronjob which imports this data into our database.
Only problem is it imports the tracking code as `26E+12`. Now when we want to check the tracking code in the backend of our site a url is pasted, so you get something like: `http://trackmynumber/26E+12...`

This is not readable for the carrier website because they are expecting `http://trackmynumber/563200000`

Is there any way to convert or extract the real number from the csv-file so it imports as a number in the database?

Comment: Are you creating csv from Excel?

Comment: I am not sure how you relate 26E+12 which is scientific notation for 26000000000000 to 563200000 (5632E+4 or 5.632E7)

Comment: What is the data type of the relevant MySQL column?

Comment: Check the datatype of you table. It might be VARCHAR

Comment: the column in my database is varchar....(15). but it needs to get the good code from the csv column (which has a value of 26E+12 (which is a number). The csv cannot be adjusted or changed, because we would have to do that every 3 hours for about 500 products).

Answer (score 0):

Change the datatype of the column which gets that value to float

Comment: The problem is solved. Seems that when opening a csv file in excel a big value or a value with leading zero's becomes a scientific cell automatic. This cannot be undone. When touched with anything other than a program like excel it wont change the cell/column so the real value will still be there when importing into database. thanks for the help.